# cannot find the file while using textscan in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a file with name test.net. I put it in the same location as the matlab working directory. Then, I put the following two lines of codes.

```
path='test.net';
[pajekFile,errmsg] = fopen(path);
```

The errmsg is: "No such file or directory". Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say there's no such file or directory. Use [`pwd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pwd.html) and [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) to ensure you're placing the file in the correct directory. I would also recommend not overloading the [`path`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html) built-in, especially with something that isn't even a path.

Comment: I can see the file. It is in the directory I want it to be, which is exactly the matlab working directory.

Comment: That's great. Did you do anything I said?

Comment: Thanks, excaza. I figured it out.